# OpenLayers snap pointermove to feature

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to use the OpenLayers `Snap` interaction with `pointermove` events.

From my understanding the `Snap` interaction should modify the coordinate of the `pointermove` event if inside the given `pixelTolerance`, but with no success.

Here is a minimal working example (the coordinate in the console should be [0, 0] when moving the cursor near the point):
https://codesandbox.io/s/openlayers-example-ie0br

Is this behaviour even possible or does snapping only work with real ol interactions like draw or modify? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It modifies the browser event used by other interactions, you would also need for example a Select interaction.  To avoid being obvious to a user If you are setting styles on feature use `style: false` for the select so it doesn't override them otherwise use the layer style  https://codesandbox.io/s/openlayers-example-r1ng0

Comment: Thank you, also for the very useful example sandbox!